# Only return specific properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have developed my first API controlled in MVC4 and through the scaffolding I have got it to automatically output a list of items:

```
// GET api/ItemList
public IEnumerable<ItemOption> GetItemOptions()
{
    var itemoptions = db.ItemOptions.Include(i => i.Item);
    return itemoptions.AsEnumerable();
}
```

This shows all the item properties from my model:

```
public class ItemOption
{
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public double PriceNet { get; set; }
}
```

How can I specify specific fields I wish to be returned? For example, I just want the ItemOptionId, Active and Name to be returned.

I have tried adding additional includes, but this seems to be at an object level.

Comment: Use `itemoptions.AsEnumerable().Select(...);`

Comment: Is your `ItemOptions` class coming from Entity Framework ?

Comment: @Habib Yes, from the EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new type to represent the properties you'd like to return:

```
public class ItemOptionResult
{
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then projecting your `ItemOption` collection, like this:

```
// GET api/ItemList
public IEnumerable<ItemOptionResult> GetItemOptions()
{`enter code here`
    var itemoptions =
        db.ItemOptions
          .Select(i => 
           new ItemOptionResult
           { 
               ItemOptionId = i.ItemOptionId, 
               Active = i.Active, 
               Name = i.Name 
           });
    return itemoptions.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: You can't return Anonymous type IEnumerable from your method.

Comment: +1, this should work, since the OP can't use EF generated class to project the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var itemoptions = db.ItemOptions.Select(io => new ItemOption()
                                              {
                                                   ItemOptionId = io.ItemOptionId,
                                                   Active = io.Active ,
                                                   Name = io.Name
                                              }
return itemoptions.AsEnumerable();
```